# defaultProps function does not accept methods from component class (Parent Child Comunication)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

This is the parent code and the whole thing renders perfectly and even the props function oncheckselection is been perfectly called by the child but i cant pass the data to my react component method getchilddata gives me undefined no properties or some other error.

```
class Supertest extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {selected : []};
    }
    componentWillReceiveProps(Nextprops) {
      console.log(Nextprops.onCheckSelection)
    }
    getchilddata(value) {
      alert('yolo')
    }
    render() {
        return (<div>
          <div>{SimpleTable(this.props)}</div>
          </div>);
    }

}

Supertest.propTypes = {
    headers: React.PropTypes.instanceOf(Immutable.List),
    descriptors: React.PropTypes.instanceOf(Immutable.List),
    data: React.PropTypes.instanceOf(Immutable.List),
    rowTransform: React.PropTypes.func,
    rowSelected: React.PropTypes.func,
    headerSelected: React.PropTypes.func,
    selectable: React.PropTypes.bool,
    onCheckSelection: React.PropTypes.func,
    prescanRows: React.PropTypes.bool
};

Supertest.defaultProps = {
    headers: List(headers),
    descriptors: List(descriptors),
    data: List(data),
    rowTransform: (() => List()),
    rowSelected: ((dataItem) => {}),
    headerSelected: ((header) => {}),
    onCheckSelection : ((items) => {this.getchilddata}),
    selectable: true,
    prescanRows: true
};
```

Child function thats been called. I can print the data in console when I edit the parent code oncheckSelection.

```
    var checkSelection = function (value) {
        props.onCheckSelection(value)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think ***this*** is refering to something different that you would like it to refer(***this***.getchilddata).

what about moving the function onCheckSelection inside the class iteself, something like:

```
    onCheckSelection(value){
        this.getchilddata(value);
        if(this.props.getchilddata){
            this.props.getchilddata(value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Said,
oncheckSelection is a props function not a class function. props.onCheckSelection(value) is called by the child and i wanna bind this to a parent function inside class and access this props function parameters value